# Run-time error '91' ... attempting to index multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

The following snippet is giving me an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error

```
cIndx = wsMain.Range(Cells(i, begCol), Cells(i, endCol)).Find("Churn", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not cIndx Is Nothing Then
    If wsMain.Cells(i, statusCol) = "Active" Then
        wsMain.Cells(i, cIndx.Column) = " "
    End If
End If
```

The first line is the culprit. My research so far suggests it has to do with the way I'm indexing the Range but official documentation says what I'm attempting is possible. I've reviewed all posts I could find on here with the same title as mine but none of them appear to be directly applicable to my situation. Any insights are much appreciated. Happy to post surrounding code if more context is helpful.

Also curious whether I can do this:

```
With wsMain
    cIndx = .Range(Cells(i, begCol), Cells(i, endCol)).Find("Churn", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not cIndx Is Nothing Then
        If .Cells(i, statusCol) = "Active" Then
            .Cells(i, cIndx.Column) = " "
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Yields the same error as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular code module, `Cells()` without a qualifying worksheet will always refer to the Activesheet, so you need to qualify those calls.
Also need to use Set when assigning a value to an object-type variable.

```
Set cIndx = wsMain.Range(wsMain.Cells(i, begCol), wsMain.Cells(i, endCol)).Find( _
                "Churn", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not cIndx Is Nothing Then
    If wsMain.Cells(i, statusCol) = "Active" Then
        wsMain.Cells(i, cIndx.Column) = " "
    End If
End If
```

Comment: The critical piece I was missing was using Set to assign a value to cIndx. Many thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Because cindx is a range I think you will find that the syntax should be:

```
Set cindx = .Range(Cells(i, begCol), Cells(i, endCol)).Find("Churn", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole)`
```

this works for me

Comment: It actually works either way but qualifying the cells might be safer I think, in case another worksheet is accidentally opened. Appreciate the effort though.